# Prevent resetting style after specific breakpoint

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

While converting a page to responsive layout, css style resets after 620px breakpoint. The affected design part is as follows. Please note **the following snippet working perfectly and given only to describe what I'm doing**. The problem occurs only if it is combined with the full code.

```css
.tfulltiny{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.tblocktiny{
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.tcelltiny{
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 color: #609;
 font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {
 body {
        margin:0 40px 0 40px;
    }
    .tblocktiny{
     width: 16%;
 }
 .tcelltiny {
     width:100%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
 .tblocktiny{
     width: 99%;
 }
 .tcelltiny {
     width:100%;
 }
}
```

```html
    <div class="tfulltiny">
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Planet</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Longitude (Deg:Min:Sec)</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Rasi</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Longitude (Deg:Min:Sec)</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Star</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblocktiny">
   <div class="tcelltiny">
    <span>Pada</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected output after 680px screensize:
[image: Expected output]

But suddenly the style disappears while crossing 620px+

[image: What I'm getting after 620px]

**The full code is so big so I cant include it here, may be the bug is in that code. However I want information on what makes styling disappear. What are the possible issues and how to resolve this?**

Edit : 
After searching, I found 620px width used 2 times in code. Don't know it have some role in this error.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
      .tblocksml{
            width: 49%;
      }
      .tcellsml {
            width:99%;
      }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      .tblocksml{
            width: 99%;
      }
      .tcellsml {
            width:99%;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a fix to this problem. Actually it is just a trick, not a proper solution. The problem occurring due to @media overlaps. So the part which faces problem must be added first place in the code. That is, cut-paste the misbehaving code in top of css and the problem will be solved. **However I know this is not a proper method, but it works for me.** I'll change this answer from best when better answer arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/118/

**CSS**

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
        .tblocktiny{
           width: 99%;
           margin-top: 0;
        }
          .tcelltiny {
            width:100%;
            color: black;
            font-weight: normal;

          }
      }
```

Other solution https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/119/

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {
      body {
        margin:0 40px 0 40px;
      }

      .tblocktiny{
        width: 16%;
         margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .tcelltiny {
         width:100%;
         color: #609;
         font-weight: bold;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I want to know what makes my styles invalid after that particular viewpoint. What are the possible reasons for that?

Comment: Its not invalid you just didn't change it in media queries.

Comment: OK. Got it. But is there any reasons for css to be invalid after a particular viewpoint?

Comment: If its correct css i don't think so. What did you want to be changed in style with your code in media queries?

Comment: I want that vertical list transformed into horizontal one while stretching. But the issue now I'm dealing with is after 620px screen-size, the style suddenly disappears. Now I tested standalone and it works perfectly. That means the error is not in above code, but somewhere else in my page. Don't know where to look in that huge code. It will be better if I got some information on why this happens.

Comment: Well this should not be a problem. `@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {}` applies to screen width `< 620px` and `@media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {}` applies to screen width `>620px`. So if you don't specify code in this queries that you want to change on this width it will stay the same or nothing will change. And all code out of queries is applied for all widths. So if you have `color` property out of media queries you have to change it in some media query if you want it to change.